# How this condition work for this set of number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\left| \{ A : (A\subseteq  \{1,2,3,..n\})\ \wedge\ (\{3\} \subseteq A)\ \wedge\ (\{5,8\}\cap A = \emptyset) \}\right |$

I need to find set A size for all $n$ cases.

I don't know if i got the question right but for example

$n=0$, $|A|=1$ because of the 2nd conditionn?

$n=3$, does that mean $|A|=3$?

and if $n <5$ would that be $|A|=4$ and etc..?

and what if $ n = 5$, would that be $|A| = 4$ because by the 3rd condition 5 and 8 dont count?

What i've came to so far:

$n<8, |A|=2^{n-2}$

$0 \leq n \leq 8, 1 \leq|A| \leq 6$

Comment: If $n \leq 2$, we can't have that $\{3\}$ is a subset of $A$, no?

Comment: @Phil but according to the 2nd statement {3}⊆A, doesn't that mean 3 is always in A?

Comment: @Phil what if $n>8$ thus $|A| = 2^{n-2}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $n \ge 8$ you are told that $3$ is in $A$ and $5,8$ are not.  How many binary choices does that leave you?  If $n \lt 3$ you cannot satisfy the requirement that $3$ be in $A$, so there are none.  How about the range from $3$ to $7$?

Comment: if $n \geq 8$ then there should be $2^{n-2}$? and if $n<3$ then only 1,2? when it said that 3  is subset of A, doesn't mean that 3 is always in A?

Comment: from 3 to 7 i think its $|A| = 3 \leq n < 6? $

Comment: No, you are guessing.  Yes, $3$ is always in $A$, so if $n \lt 3$ there are none at all because for $n=2$ we need $\{3\} \subseteq A$ but also $A \subseteq \{1,2\}$.  These are incompatible.  If $n=4$, you have to have $3$ and you can have any of $1,2,4$ that you like.  That is three binary choices, so there are $2^3=8$ different sets in $A$.

Comment: why $n=4$ is $2^{3}$? shouldn't it be $A = {1,2,3,4}$? and for $n < 2$ is always $|A| =0$ because it doesn't satisfy the 2nd condition?

Comment: $A$ is a set of sets.  It is the set of all subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots n\}$ that satisfy the condition on $3,5,8$.  For $n=3$ we have $A=\{\{3\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ for a size of $4$.  For $n=4$ you can add $4$ or not to any of these, so the size of $A$ is $8$.  In your original question there should really be braces inside the $|$s to indicate this.

Comment: What I gathered is when n<3 then |A| = 0 because it doesn't satisfy the 2nd condition. and when n=4 its $|A| = 0 \leq n \leq 4 $?

Comment: Your last statement makes no sense. What is $|A|$ supposed to be equal to?  It has to be a number, not $0 \le n \le 4$.  It is not the size of one of the sets in $A$, which can range from $1 to 3$ when $n=4$.   It is the number of sets in $A$.  I showed it is $8$ when $n=4$ in my last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116738/discussion-between-light-lamps-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: One last question, how did you come to conclusions that A is set of sets? i thought for example if n=4 then it can A= {1,2,3,4} or A={1,2,3}. Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: The original question is written in set builder notation.  It is the set of all $A$s that meet the requirement of being a subset of $[n]$ having $3$ and not having $5,8$.  The $|$ bars compute the number of sets meeting that requirement.  Really we should not have been talking of $|A|$, but have given that set a name like $B$ and been talking about $|B|$.